# Kак правильно говорить?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Помоги пожалуйста разобраться в споре. Как правильно сказать, велосипед не помещается в машину? Или...велосипед не влазит в машину? Или...велосипед не залазит в машину? И есть ли такое слово в русском языке, как не ЗАЛАЗЯЕТ велосипед в машину? Я думаю что велосипед не помещается в машину! Потому что залезть он не может и не залазить тоже, тем более не ЗАЛЯЗЯЕТ! По деревьям и по крышам лазить он еще не научился! Спасибо.

Comment: Правильно говорить: «Помогите».

Comment: +1 за минутку юмора.

Answer (score 2):

Нейтральные синонимы к нейтральному ПОМЕЩАТЬСЯ — вмещаться, умещаться, укладываться.

Остальные глаголы либо просторечные, либо разговорные, и я не вижу причин их избегать.

Велосипед не влазит, не влезает... но нет как класса глагола залазиет, тем более в форме залазает/залязает.

Хотя вот, народ острит:

[Всегда шутила про себя, что живу, как трамвай: один слазит, другой залазиет.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%B5%D1%82&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjSp9ic4eTjAhUjmYsKHSyYAiYQ_AUIFygB&biw=1920&bih=969)

Answer (score 2):

> *Не помещается (не умещается) в машин**е***;

менее формально (в некоторых словарях помечается как *разговорное*):

> *не влезает в машин**у** (в старые джинсы).*

Остальные предлагавшиеся варианты просторечны. Вариант **не влезает**, помимо широкого употребления в книгах (далеко не только в речи художественных персонажей), фиксируется *Академическим толковым словарём* от РАН (2016),

https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=UE8_DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA52&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&sig=ACfU3U0Es1ZfU2ZzLdM6ff7daJ9Hha2g5A&w=1280

так что его употребление в значении "не уместиться" не ограничивается разговорной речью и возможно на письме, в непринуждённом повествовании или рассуждении.